# Enable Spark on Same Node As Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I am trying to test out Spark so I can summarize some data I have in Cassandra. I've been through all the DataStax tutorials and they are very vague as to how you actually enable spark. The only indication I can find is that it comes enabled automatically when you select "Analytics" node during install. However, I have an existing Cassandra node and I don't want to have to use a different machine for testing as I am just evaluating everything on my laptop.

**Is it possible to just enable Spark on the same node and deal with any performance implications? If so how can I enable it so that it can be tested?**

I see the folders there for Spark (although I'm not positive all the files are present) but when I check to see if it's set to Spark master, it says that no spark nodes are enabled.

> dsetool sparkmaster

I am using Linux Ubuntu Mint.

*I'm just looking for a quick and dirty way to get my data averaged and so forth and Spark seems like the way to go since it's a massive amount of data, but I want to avoid having to pay to host multiple machines (at least for now while testing).*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,  Spark is also able to interact with a cluster even if it is not on all the nodes.

### Package install

```
Edit the /etc/default/dse file, and then edit the appropriate line 
to this file, depending on the type of node you want:
...

Spark nodes:
SPARK_ENABLED=1
HADOOP_ENABLED=0
SOLR_ENABLED=0
```

Then restart the DSE service

http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/reference/refDseServ.html

### Tar Install

Stop DSE on the node and the restart it using the following command

```
From the install directory:
...
Spark only node: $ bin/dse cassandra -k - Starts Spark trackers on a cluster of Analytics nodes.
```

http://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.5/datastax_enterprise/reference/refDseStandalone.html

Comment: I just want to clarify that I am trying to install Spark on the same machine as my database where I am doing the logging. In other words, I am using one machine for everything. Is still inline with what you are saying?

Comment: Yep, DSE always starts C* on any node you run it on.

Comment: I think that worked! 'll probably end up creating a second issue, but any idea why DSE_ENV could not be determined pops up? I get it when running demos and simple things like nodetool status. I noticed that echo $DSE_HOME returns nothing in the console as well and this appears to get set in the DSE_ENV file.

Comment: In case you want to take a look, I created another issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30135081/dse-env-could-not-be-determined

Answer (score 0):

Enable spark by changing **SPARK_ENABLED=1**
using the command: `sudo nano /usr/share/dse/resources/dse/conf/dse.default`