# DSE_ENV could not be determined

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, nodetool

I setup DataStax Enterprise 4.6.6 on a Linux Ubuntu machine. OpsCenter and DevCenter are working fine. I able to write to the database, etc. with no issues.

However many of the demos and command line tools return the following error:

> DSE_ENV could not be determined

One such example of when this occurs is:

> nodetool status

I found a file called `DSE_ENV.sh` which appears to set some environment variables such as `DSE_HOME`. But when I `echo $DSE_HOME` for example the variable is not set. I don't know if maybe this file is never getting called or what is causing the issue.

I found this article which is specific to the the `dse` service not starting, *which is not the case with me*:
https://support.datastax.com/hc/en-us/articles/204226189-DSE-fails-to-start-with-error-DSE-ENV-could-not-be-determined

I tried however to run the permissions commands it mentions but no luck.

Comment: How did you install? Tarball? Package installer?

Comment: I used the DataStax Enterprise install from the website. The file is: DataStaxOpsCenter-5.1.1.2015031808-linux-x64-installer.run

Comment: So you deployed the DSE node using OpsCenter?

Comment: Yes I installed OpsCenter afterwards: DataStaxOpsCenter-5.1.1.2015031808-linux-x64-installer.run

Comment: I'm not clear. You installed OpsCenter using DataStaxOpsCenter-5.1.1.2015031808-linux-x64-installer.run. How did you install DSE? Not using OpsC I assume since you said "after"

Comment: Sorry  I pasted the wrong link the first time: DataStaxEnterprise-4.6.6.2015050110-linux-x64-installer.run

Comment: Ah the GUI installer, gotcha. I forget about that option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77369/discussion-between-phact-and-kingofhypocrites).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Worked with KOH on this over chat.

TL;DR: we had to add

```
export DSE_ENV=/usr/share/dse/bin/dse-env.sh
```

to his ~/.bashrc because it wasn't getting picked up.

For some reason this seems to be happening in the DSE GUI installer. I will look further into this and update.

Comment: I am having this exact issue with the same version of the datastax. I did everything as the OP did. I also added this to bashrc but still no luck. This started happening after the system recovered from a power failure. Funny thing is the same setup in two other nodes are working fine.

Comment: sounds like your installation is somehow corrupted. Did you try to re-install the binaries? I prefer the tarball or package installers over the .run installer.

Comment: Is there anything else you can think of that I can try without uninstalling the binaries.

Comment: No, I think it's the fastest way to fixing the issue. Also you won't loose data or anything. Don't remove your data directories and backup your config files.

Comment: gotcha. Gonna do it now.